# System.Security.Claims missing

Tags: c#, asp.net

need a bit of help with an issue. I have developed a web app that needs to use claims to get info. I am trying to setup the using statement System.Security.Claims but claims is not an option. I have AccessControl, Authentication, Cryptography, Permissions, Policy, Principal and util. All the tutorials i am seeing have the claims option imported. What am i doing wrong?

I have references to microsoft.identitymodel as well as system.security in my references but im still at a loss.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of .NET Framework are you targeting?

Comment: to be honest, not sure. 4.0 i think. is there a way to tell?

Comment: System.Security.Claims requires 4.5 minimum; you can find the target framework version by right-clicking on your assembly and selecting Properties, and checking the "Application" tab.

Comment: That worked. I wish you had submitted that as an answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

System.Security.Claims requires 4.5 minimum; you can find the target framework version by right-clicking on your assembly and selecting Properties, and checking the "Application" tab.